# How to find a value between two range in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

How do I find the exact record to fetch the price if I pass the weight and respective fields.

**for eg:**

if I am passing `weight and selecting state, district` as below,

```
$weight = 100
$state_id = 1
$district_id = 1
```

The prompt record that should be displayed is 1, I am not getting any record.

**My Controller**

```
$shipping_rate = ShippingRate::where('state_id', $state_id)->where('district_id', $district_id)->where(function ($query) use ($weight) {
    $query->where('weight_from', '<=', $weight);
    $query->where('weight_to', '>=', $weight);
})->first();
```

I noticed that the when I remove the  `$query->where('weight_to', '>=', $weight);` results are being fetched. I assume that this could be not accurate.

So how do I find the values in between the range?

When I use

**Here is my JSON:**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "state_id": 1,
    "district_id": 1,
    "weight_to": "0",
    "weight_from": "1450",
    "price": "100",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-06-04T06:07:48.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-07T16:54:58.000000Z"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "state_id": 1,
    "district_id": 1,
    "weight_to": "1450",
    "weight_from": "2450",
    "price": "150",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-06-04T06:07:48.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-04T06:07:48.000000Z"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "state_id": 1,
    "district_id": 1,
    "weight_to": "2450",
    "weight_from": "3450",
    "price": "250",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-06-04T06:07:48.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-04T06:07:48.000000Z"
}, {
    "id": 4,
    "state_id": 1,
    "district_id": 5,
    "weight_to": "100",
    "weight_from": "1450",
    "price": "50",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-06-04T06:07:48.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-04T06:07:48.000000Z"
}, {
    "id": 5,
    "state_id": 1,
    "district_id": 6,
    "weight_to": "100",
    "weight_from": "1450",
    "price": "50",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "created_at": "2021-06-04T06:07:48.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-06-04T06:07:48.000000Z"
}]
```

**table structure**

[image]

Comment: You can change `->first()` to `->toSql()` so you can see the resulting query (but only for debugging purposes)

Comment: @matiaslauriti Added ->toSql() -- select * from `shipping_rates` where `state_id` = ? and `district_id` = ? and (`weight_from` <= ? and `weight_to` >= ?) and `shipping_rates`.`deleted_at` is null

Comment: @JohnLobo it returns empty results..

Comment: $shipping_rate = ShippingRate::where('state_id', $state_id)
                ->where('district_id', $district_id)
                ->where(function ($query) use ($weight) {
                    $query->orWhere('weight_from', '<=', $weight);
                    $query->orWhere('weight_to', '>=', $weight);
                })->first();

Comment: @AnkitaDobariya Thanks, that worked, could you please highlight what I did wrong

Comment: I think the first record is not fetched because 1450 is not <= 100, `$query->where('weight_from', '<=', $weight)`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I tried that too but same results

Comment: I mean 'weight_from', '<=', $weight results in false because weight_from = 1450 for the first record, and $weight = 100

Answer (score 2):

Hi you have a small issue, not syntax issue it's a logical issue.
Just replace this

```
->where(function ($query) use ($weight) {
            $query->orWhere('weight_from', '<=', $weight);
            $query->orWhere('weight_to', '>=', $weight);
        })
```

With this

```
->where(function ($query) use ($weight) {
            $query->Where('weight_from', '>=', $weight);
            $query->Where('weight_to', '<=', $weight);
        })
```

Here your `weight_form` is greater that `weight_to`, so it will work.

**OR**
You can try this

```
  ShippingRate::where('state_id', $state_id)
        ->where('district_id', $district_id)
        -->whereRaw('"'.$weight.'" between `weight_to` and `weight_from`')
        ->first();
```

Comment: I tried it, Not working. can we this be replaced to raw sql

Comment: Try the both solution once again

Comment: I am getting reults for the last one, give me some time, testing few possibilities